# Does the feat Fire God's Blessing provide magical healing or mundane healing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, magic, healing

Does the feat [Fire God's Blessing](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fire%20God%27s%20Blessing) provide magical healing or mundane healing? I can't find any references as to which kind of healing this is.

> When in combat, if you deal fire damage to an enemy, you heal 1 hit point. You can only benefit from this healing once per round. Attacks that cause a target to catch on fire heal you each round the target takes fire damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is an example of *magical* healing.

According to the [Pathfinder SRD on Archives of Nethys](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Healing&Category=Injury%20and%20Death), natural healing<sup>1</sup> is

> With a full night’s rest (8 hours of sleep or more), you recover 1 hit point per character level. Any significant interruption during your rest prevents you from healing that night.

and magical healing is

> Various abilities and spells can restore hit points.

It is clear that this is healing not granted by a rest and falls under the magical healing umbrella.

---

<sup>1</sup> The wiki seems to be formatted incorrectly, as *Natural Healing* is part of the first paragraph in the block there.

Comment: that is the perfect answer that i needed thank you very much

Comment: @ReggiElliott Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer! Though I'd wait a day or so to see if any other, better, answers pop up :)